# Is there a hadith "...when commanding people to do something, he had already done or raced to it and done it"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I am looking for a hadith I heard. It basically says that the Prophet (Peace Be upon Him) when commanding people to do something, he had already done or raced to it and done it. I would like to know if this is a Hadith, is it authentic? and what book is it in?

Comment: I am thinking, this could be probably about an Imam (Imam Abu Hanifa or someone else), not the prophet.

Answer (score 1):

This is only almost true, but not exactly. According to a Shia Hadith the exception is the "Voteyre Sallah" that the holy prophet was encouraging Muslims for doing this praying but himself wasn't doing it as he knew his death time, I don't know if Suuni Muslims are familiar with this praying?

Godspeed